# Javascript url 404 error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm have a problem loading a site. Using this code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //url: '@Url.Action("/TellFriendPopup")',
        url: '/Property/TellFriendPopup',

        data: { "SenderName": SenderName, "senderMail": senderMail, "receiverMail": receiverMail, "comments": comments, "urlLink": urlLink, "subjectId": subjectId },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#result").html("<ul><li>Name: " + data.nameret + "</li><li>Email: " + data.emailret + "</li><li>Message: " + data.messageret + "</li></ul>");

        $(".dialog").dialog("close");
    },
```

The problem is that I had to move the code to a JavaScript file, instead of the MVC4 View, where i could use the `@Url.Action` method. But it is not working in JavaScript. It Just gives me this error `POST http://localhost:54717/Property/ContactPopup 404 (Not Found)`. The reason as I can see is that it's the Globalization that it's missing. Because the url should look like this  `http://localhost:54717/da/Property/ContactPopup` or  `http://localhost:54717/en/Property/ContactPopup`

Comment: Why can you add `/da/Property/ContactPopup` in `ajax` call

Comment: Because if the language is english. the string is /en/Property/ContactPopup instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing this: `url: '/Property/TellFriendPopup',`

to this `url: '../Property/TellFriendPopup',`

Answer (score 2):

You could get the first folder of the pathname. As long as that is where the language code is on every page.

```
var language = location.pathname.split("/")[1];

url: language + '/Property/TellFriendPopup'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have `language` in `hidden` field.

```
var language = document.getElementById('language`).value;

url: '/' + language + '/Property/TellFriendPopup'
```